# Extjs how to get list of all events of component dynamically

Tags: events, extjs, dynamic, field

I want to get the list of all events for any particular component dynamically. For example : If I take a Textfield , how can I get all possible events that are mentioned in ExtJs API Doc. so that user can choose and assign the event for any component.

Answer (score 1):

```
component.events
```

Contains the list you need. You could have found out by yourself reading the source of [addEvents method](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/Observable.html#Ext-util-Observable-method-addEvents), which is linked from any [event](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/AbstractComponent.html#Ext-AbstractComponent-event-activate) you wanted to find in a list.

Comment: I don't believe this will work in 5 to retrieve the full list of *possible* events, only for events that have listeners.

Comment: Yes.. We only get list of events which is assigned explicitly to any particular component.

Answer (score 0):

For those still wanting an answer to this, https://coderwall.com/p/jnqupq/easily-capture-all-events-on-a-component-in-extjs has provided a nice means of doing so.

When debugging an ExtJS application, you'll often find it useful to listen to all events fired by a specific component. There is actually a handy built-in static method to do this called Ext.util.Observable.capture().

Here's a handy snippet that simply logs the event name and all arguments:

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture(myObj, function(evname) {console.log(evname, arguments);})
```

Even better, if you're currently inspecting your component's main element in your browser's developer tools, you can do this:

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture(Ext.getCmp($0.id), function(evname) {console.log(evname, arguments);})
```

Where $0 is the currently selected element. Should work fine in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari.

If you don't want those logs to pollute your console anymore, simply call releaseCapture on your object:

```
Ext.util.Observable.releaseCapture(myObj);
```

This removes all captures on a given object so you don't have to reference your listener explicitly (which was likely an anonymous function :)).

Bonus tip: also be sure to check out the observe method which does something similar but allows you to listen to all events fired by all instances of a given class.